# How to Change uitextfield leftView image tintColor on editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to achieve UITextField editing or not editing style like this:

[image]

But the trickiest part for me is How to change that left image tint color. **I have achieved this so far:**

[image]

My code:

UITextField

```
lazy var email: UITextField = {
    let name = UITextField()
    name.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5
    name.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.55, green: 0.61, blue: 0.69, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    name.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    name.placeholder = "Email"
    name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    name.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.55, green: 0.61, blue: 0.69, alpha: 1)
    name.backgroundColor = .clear
    name.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    name.delegate = self
    name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return name
}()
```

leftImage func:

```
func addLeftImageTo(txtField: UITextField, andImage img: UIImage) {

    let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42.75, height: 40))
    let centerX: CGFloat = (leftView.frame.midX) - (img.size.width / 2)
    let centerY: CGFloat = (leftView.frame.midY) - (img.size.height / 2)
    let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: centerX + 2 , y: centerY - 1, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height))
    leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    leftImageView.image = img
    leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)
    txtField.leftView = leftView
    txtField.leftViewMode = .always
}
```

Adding leftImages:

```
let emailLeftImg = UIImage(named: "ic_txt_field_email")
addLeftImageTo(txtField: email, andImage: emailLeftImg!)

let passwordLeftImg = UIImage(named: "ic_txt_field_password")
addLeftImageTo(txtField: password, andImage: passwordLeftImg!)
```

editingBegains and Ending:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.setTextBorder(textField: textField, color: UIColor.white, borderColor: UIColor.white, isSelected: true)

}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.setTextBorder(textField: textField, color: UIColor.clear, borderColor: UIColor(red: 0.55, green: 0.61, blue: 0.69, alpha: 0.5),  isSelected: false)
}


func setTextBorder(textField: UITextField, color: UIColor, borderColor: UIColor, isSelected: Bool) {
    textField.backgroundColor = color
    textField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    textField.tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.33, alpha: 1)
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = false

    if isSelected == true {
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.125
    } else {
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 0
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
    }

}
```

I had tried adding this code to change Image color but it didn't work.

```
var picTintColor: Bool = false
```

In LeftImage func:

```
if picTintColor == true {
        leftImageView.image = img.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        leftImageView.tintColor = .blue
    } else {
        leftImageView.image = img
    }
```

And in editingBegains and Ending func:

```
if isSelected == true {
        picTintColor = true
    } else {
        picTintColor = false
    }
```

I'm a complete noob in IOS programming so thanks for your patience and sorry for my bad english. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According the code ,it actually can not pass **isSelected** signal to the **leftImageView**,maybe **leftImageView** get in laster is not the earlier ,or the signal not pass successly.
I suggest that a easy way to do, just in **editingBegains and Ending:** to do what you want change the imageview,like this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     let emailLeftImg = UIImage(named: "ic_txt_field_email")
     addLeftImageTo(txtField: email, andImage: emailLeftImg!)
}

func addLeftImageTo(txtField: UITextField, andImage img: UIImage) {

let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42.75, height: 40))
let centerX: CGFloat = (leftView.frame.midX) - (img.size.width / 2)
let centerY: CGFloat = (leftView.frame.midY) - (img.size.height / 2)
let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: centerX + 2 , y: centerY - 1, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height))
leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
if picTintColor == true {
    leftImageView.image = img.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    leftImageView.tintColor = .blue
} else {
    leftImageView.image = img
}
leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)
txtField.leftView = leftView
txtField.leftViewMode = .always
```

}
and in end delgate method ,just do that ,you can try this way to test.Hope to help you.